# Tensorflow Parse CSV Iterator Shift by One Row

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am following the [wide_deep](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide) tutorial but I am having a hard time reproducing the example of reading in a CSV properly.

Here is my code to generate a dummy CSV:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'y': [1,2,3],
    'x1':[4,5,6],
    'x2':[7.0,8.0,9.0],
    'x3':['ten','eleven','twelve']
})
file_path = 'tmp.csv'
data.to_csv(file_path, index=False, header=False)
```

And this is what the CSV looks like:

[image]

Then I tried to read in the file with:

```
def parse_csv(line):
    _CSV_COLUMNS = ['x1','x2','x3','y']
    defaults = [[0],[0.0],[''],[0]]
    columns = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=defaults)
    features = dict(zip(_CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
    labels = features.pop('y')
    return features, tf.equal(labels, 3)

dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_path)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

for i in range(3):
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    for k,v in features.items():
        print(k, v.eval())
    print('-'*50)
```

And the output looks like:

```
x1 4
x2 8.0
x3 b'twelve'
--------------------------------------------------
<error message: OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): End of sequence>
```

Why it is not `4, 7.0, 'ten'`?

Comment: I am unable to duplicate your results.  Please post some real data, not a picture, as my version of your picture works fine.

Comment: @StephenRauch, the data was generated by the first snippet of the code. The picture is only for reference. Do you get 4,7.0 and 'ten' then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is due to the fact that the `v.eval()` will advance the iterator for all components.  From the ([DOCS](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator)):

> Note that evaluating any of next1, next2, or next3 will advance the iterator for all components. A typical consumer of an iterator will include all components in a single expression.

One way to get what you are after is:

#### Code:

```
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
features, labels = iterator.get_next()

for i in range(3):
    for k, v in sess.run(features).items():
        print(k, v)
    print('-' * 50)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'y': [1, 2, 3],
    'x1': [4, 5, 6],
    'x2': [7.0, 8.0, 9.0],
    'x3': ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve']
})
file_path = 'tmp.csv'
data.to_csv(file_path, index=False, header=False)

def parse_csv(line):
    _CSV_COLUMNS = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'y']
    defaults = [[0], [0.0], [''], [0]]
    columns = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=defaults)
    features = dict(zip(_CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
    labels = features.pop('y')
    return features, tf.equal(labels, 3)

dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_path)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
features, labels = iterator.get_next()

for i in range(3):
    for k, v in sess.run(features).items():
        print(k, v)
    print('-' * 50)
```

#### Results:

```
x1 4
x2 7.0
x3 b'ten'
--------------------------------------------------
x1 5
x2 8.0
x3 b'eleven'
--------------------------------------------------
x1 6
x2 9.0
x3 b'twelve'
```

Comment: It is very interesting how `sess.run(features)` will just update for every loop, sort of like features = dataset.get_next() got called in a hidden way.